# Increment number using AWK

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file which contains the following:

```
export TM_FUNCTION=SUM08619 ;export TM_PARAM_SEQNO=2 ;export PSEUDO_USER=HIHI; . /projects/MSS/LEE1MP/shells/sumh8701.sh  001 DATE:W:0:C:D:1:11:1:N:: DATE:W:0:C:D:1:11:N:1:W: IT ++ ++ 000052233714 DATE:W:0:C:D:1:11:N:N:: 100000 N FMPOST A / &
```

If i run the following value 100000 is returned:

```
awk -F' ' '{ print $17 }' filename
```

I would like to increment $17 using a script by 1 each time i run what is the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```sh
awk '{$17=$17+1}1' filename > tmp && mv tmp filename
```

Calling this each time will increment Field 17 by one.

If you have a GNU `awk` you may use

```sh
awk -i inplace '{$17=$17+1}1' filename
```

Comment: awk supports pre/post increment operators so `$17++` instead of `$17=$17+1` would work too.

Answer (score 0):

```
mawk '++$17_'  # either form works
gawk '_$17++'
```

The extra `_` is a somewhat uncommon but still `POSIX-compliant` way to

> **force string concat with empty string `_`**

thus guaranteeing print out of all rows even if `$17` got incremented from `-1` to `0` due to this `awk` peculiarity :

> numeric zero (`+0`) := `false`

- but

> ***string*** zero (`"0"`)  := **`TRUE`** (since it's a non-empty string)